# Can someone help me fix these error in "App.js" (Find the files on github)

Tags: javascript, html, css

To give some context i am following a tutorial on how to make a simple counter using js & react and the tutorial isnt the best at all... so i tried some and i am getting 2 errors in my "App.js" file but it doesnt tell me what?

So this is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMsQwNTKJsA

And all my code is on github right here: https://github.com/pandast3ph4n/Counter-with-a-goal/tree/main

So this is the line of code which is getting the 2 errors

```
export default funtion App(){
    const [count , setCount] = React.useState(0)
```

Now maybe to fix you need the other files but they are public on github right now.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not importing useState in your App.js file

Change the import statement on the top of the file to

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

P/s: Next time, you should also put the error that you're getting in your question as well so that others can identify the problem easier